# Rails through-model modification on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I'm not sure of what the most useful title would be for this question, but here's the scenario. A model in my application can link to other examples of itself via a through model:

```
class Record < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :record_associations
  has_many :linked_records, through: :record_associations
  has_many :references, foreign_key: :linked_record_id, class_name: 'RecordAssociation'
  has_many :linking_records, through: :references, source: :record
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :record_associations, allow_destroy: true
end

class RecordAssociation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :record
  belongs_to :linked_record, :class_name => 'Record'
  belongs_to :label
end

class Label < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :record_associations
end
```

This model is therefore directional, each record having many linked_records, linking_records and so on. The labels should reflect this, for example "record A replaces Record B", "record B is_replaced_by record A", and so on. One way to do this would be to have two labels as in the above example, another would be only to have the one link "A replaces B" and, when viewing B, to look for links to it to find out that it's replaced by A.

It's this latter solution I'd prefer, but that brings up the question of how to make it work with controllers. As this is an API-only application, I can create a Record by posting params such as:

```
{record: {
  name: 'example',
  record_association_attributes: {
    linked_record_id: 1,
    label_id: 2
  }
}}.to_json
```

But, if the label specifies that the record and linked_record should be the other way around, how could I create it? I thought of passing through an additional virtual attribute on the record_association (e.g. _reverse) which if specified would do something like this in the RecordAssociation:

```
before_validation :swap_links

def swap_links
  if _reverse == 1
   record, linked_record = linked_record, record
  end
end
```

But, no luck. Presumably "record" doesn't exist yet, which wouldn't help. I also wondered about deleting and re-creating the link, reversed, after save, but I'll need to run some complex validations depending on the label and the contents of the records, so this might be tricky.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, an easier solution was to remove the accepts_nested_attributes_for from Record, and have the front-end application make a separate post to the record_associations_controller to create the relationship. Then, both Records already exist and their IDs can be supplied in whichever order the user prefers.